# boost filtering_ostream reach race condition at end of function call

Tags: c++, boost

While using the boost filtering_stream and gzip, I was able to get stuck in a race condition, not sure this is universal or only particular to my boost version 1.63.0.  I am using gcc 7.3.0 on ubuntu.  Think this post may help other people getting into the same trouble.

I have verified that all other functions work fine.

Here is my code setup in an abbreviated version

This is a class definition file fool.cpp.  Not showing the exception handling code for clarity.

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
namespace bio=boost::iostreams;
...

void CLASSNAME::cook(const string& fq1, const string& fq2, const array<string,3>& outq, const string& logfile) {

   bio::filtering_istream ins1, ins2;
   ifstream inf1(fq1, std::ios_base::in | std::ios::binary);
   ifstream inf2(fq2, std::ios_base::in | std::ios::binary);
   ins1.push(bio::gzip_decompressor());
   ins1.push(inf1);
   ins2.push(bio::gzip_decompressor());
   ins2.push(inf2);
   ofstream outf1, outf2, outf3;
   outf1.open(outq[0], std::ios_base::binary);
   outf2.open(outq[1], std::ios_base::binary);
   outf3.open(outq[2], std::ios_base::binary); bio::filtering_ostream ous1, ous2, ous3;
   ous1.push(bio::gzip_compressor()); ous1.push(outf1);
   ous2.push(bio::gzip_compressor()); ous2.push(outf2);
   ous3.push(bio::gzip_compressor()); ous3.push(outf3);

   while (read(ins1) && read(ins2)) {
      ous1 << "some data";
      ous2 << "more data";
      ous3 << "bar data";
      repeated millions times
   }
   // If the following lines are removed then the race 
   // condition goes away
   ofstrream log(logfile);
   log << "write some log data"
}
```

The race condition goes away if I remove the log file writing part. Not sure my code got any logical error or not.  But please comment. This piece of code will write the results to 3 files.  You can read from the first two output files while the program hung there forever, but you cannot read from the third output file.  I have added the debug code showing that the function stuck at the end of the function. If running in debugger, it was stuck inside the boost library.  Any boost author on the iostream part, should use this as a test case for debugging the race condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "race condition"?  I don't see any threads in your code. What is desired behavior of this code and how does it differ from actual behavior? *"Not showing the exception handling code for clarity"* I think it would be better to show it.

Comment: By race condition, I mean the boos io process got stuck if I start another ofstream object.  It was not making any progress.  Kind like a bug somewhere with the boost library. This may have been fixed in newer version of boost. This wasted half of day of my time. Hope this can save other people's time.